# Can't correctly use try doc.getElementsByClass("h4 font-weight-bold mb-0 ") in SWIFT

Tags: swift, web-scraping, swiftsoup

I need to scrape the third html div, given the class. I have this code that scrape the first element, but I can't figure it out how to scrape only the third element

```
let countryDiv: Element = try doc.getElementsByClass("h4 font-weight-bold mb-0 ").first()!
self.nodeList[index].country = try countryDiv.html()
```

I'm searching for something equivalent to

```
try doc.getElementsByClass("h4 font-weight-bold mb-0 ").third()!
```

which obviously doesn't works.

Comment: `try doc.getElementsByClass("h4 font-weight-bold mb-0 ")[2]` - I guess it's enough

Comment: Yep, it worked :) I was quite silly not trying it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment from [Vadim Nikolaev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5928311/vadim-nikolaev):

> try doc.getElementsByClass("h4 font-weight-bold mb-0 ")[2] - I guess it's enough

Accessing HTML child elements can be achieved using the `[]` syntax where 0 corresponds to the first child, and 2 - in your case, corresponds to the 3rd child element.